# Building gem throws IOError

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Trying to build a gem like so.

```
gem build my-awesome-theme.gemspec
```

And for some unknown reason it's throwing the following error.

```
/Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb:249:in `write': closed stream (IOError)
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb:249:in `close'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb:87:in `ensure in new'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb:87:in `new'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package.rb:231:in `block in build'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package.rb:230:in `open'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package.rb:230:in `build'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/package.rb:111:in `build'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/commands/build_command.rb:48:in `execute'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:167:in `process_args'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:137:in `run'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
from /Users/robertrawlins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Have tried complete rebuild of the ruby environment using RVM, and fresh clone of the gem source from GitHub but the problem persists.

Running Mac OSX, RVM and Ruby 2.3.1

Any help greatly received. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some help on the #ruby-lang IRC channel I managed to track this issue to an outdated version of rubygems, bumped it from 2.2 to 2.6 and problem appears to have gone away.